# Using AFNetworking to download two images from URL results occasional error in log

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am currently using AFNetworking's custom `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` to download two images from URLS such as the following:

```
[self.topPicture setImageWithURL:upperPicture];
[self.bottomPicture setImageWithURL:lowerPicture];
```

and around 20% of time this would work fine, although the rest of the time I get the following error:

`<Error>: ImageIO: CGImageReadSessionGetCachedImageBlockData *** CGImageReadSessionGetCachedImageBlockData: readSession [0x8a4ebd0] has bad readRef [0x8a50f30]`

I am unsure if this is due to the fact that I am trying to set two images to the screen at the same time (and on the main thread), or the fact that I did not configure AFNetworking correctly.

**Update:**

I am using Parse API's [query](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS) function to get a user's profile pictures using the code

```
NSArray *foundMatches = [queryForMatches findObjects]; //each "match" is a NSDictionary
```

of which the query is also ran on the main thread.  Later on, I retrieve a user's picture URL using something akin to

```
matchedUser[@"user_picture"] //user_picture is a string, which I then set to a new NSURL withString
```

before passing this to `setImageWithURL:` function.  At least from what I have seen, everything is retrieved on the main thread.

**Update 2:**

I tried just downloading just one picture using `getImageWithURL`, and this works fine and I do not get the error described above.

Comment: Are you doing this in your main thread? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958178/loading-uiimage-in-background-thread-causes-imageio-error

Comment: @Patrick - thanks.  I am indeed doing this on my main thread, and this is probably what is causing the error.  Because I am still very new to iOS, I wasn't sure what was meant by "render your images files into CGImageRefs and passing it back to the main thread".  Is there an example that I could follow to see more on this?  Thanks!

Comment: You should be doing this on your main thread. AFNetworking takes care of the background thread. If you already are in your main thread something else is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I added a bit more to the question body if its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Are those two lines of code executing in a background thread?

According to Apples [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/).

> Note: For the most part, UIKit classes should be used only from an
>   application’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes
>   derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your
>   application’s user interface in any way.

Comment: They are not - they are currently on the main thread, which is likely the cause of the issue.  How would I be able to put them on a background thread, and when the images are finished downloading set them to properties in my view controller?  Thanks!

Comment: That's likely not the issue. `setImageWithURL:` will spawn a new thread to perform, so the fact that you're calling it from the main thread doesn't matter. This is because a `NSOperationQueue` is used under the hood and since iOS 4, *operations are always executed on a separate thread* ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html]))