# Load UIImage in background Thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiimage, ios8

Is it possible to load a UIImage in a background thread without causing threading problems?
If not what is the best way of doing it? I'm using iOS 8. This is the way I do it right now:

```
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: fileName];

        // only update UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self setImage: image];
        });

    });
```

Comment: What is wrong with you current example ?

Comment: I once had CG ImageIO errors when loading images in the background, so I wondered why they happen. People here said that you shouldn't load UIImages in the background and that would fix it.

Comment: Maybe `imageWithContextOfURl` should help you , just instead of url put the path of ur `nsbundle` as url.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962561/set-uiimageview-image-using-a-url

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're doing is structurally sound, but I don't know whether `imageNamed:` is thread-safe — and I have no reason to believe that it is. You should always assume that things are *not* thread-safe unless you are told otherwise by the documentation. In this case, the [documentation specifically says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:) that it is *not*:

> You can not assume that this method is thread safe.

In my view, you should ask yourself whether you need to do this at all. `imageNamed:` includes a caching mechanism that should relieve you of whatever you are worried about. In any case, premature optimization is a waste of your time and brainpower. Is there really an issue here? Use Instruments to find out; don't use intuition or instinct.

If the problem is that your images are too large and in a bad choice of format — for example, you are using very large JPEGs — it would be better to concentrate on correcting *that*.

**EDIT** The iOS 9 documentation now says: "In iOS 9 and later, this method is thread safe." This suggests both that my answer was correct and that the problem is now solved.

Comment: Thanks for you fast response. I realize that there is caching with imageNamed, but though the first load will take time. I'm loading heavy images for the background and I want to present them as they finished loading, so they user see no lag at all.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense. If they take time to load, there _is_ a lag, and that lag is not going to be magically removed just because you call `imageNamed:` on a background thread. I think you should be asking yourself why there is a lag. If your images are so big that they take a long time to load, you are already in serious trouble. There is absolutely no point loading an image larger than you can display; it wastes time, memory, and processing power. An image no larger than you can display will not take significant time to load, especially if it is a `png`.

Comment: What I've seen is that `-[UIImage imageNamed:]` _used_ to be thread-safe… until iOS 8. Since then I'm seeing lots of crashes caused by calling it on a background thread, something we've been doing for years without trouble.

Comment: @DarkDust Very useful info, thanks for adding it. One could quibble and say that `imageNamed:` was probably _not_ actually thread-safe - nothing is thread-safe unless we are explicitly informed that it is - but your experience, that you were formerly able to use it in the background (even though you presumably should not have been doing so) and now you can't, is certainly of interest.

Comment: @DarkDust Docs specifically say of `imageNamed:` "You can not assume that this method is thread safe." So if you were always doing this, you were always doing it wrong.

Comment: An addendum a year+ later: Apple has updated its docs to explicitly state that `[UIImage imageNamed:]` is indeed thread-safe in iOS 9 and later. Which is really awesome news. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:

Comment: @PeterE That's great; do you want me to add that to my answer?

Comment: Yeah, might be worth adding a note to your answer that the situation has changed (for the better) in iOS 9...

Comment: @PeterE It's strange... Some crash occurs in our app when calling `-imageName:` in background thread ( iOS 9 only, 0.4% crash rate ). 