# UICollectionView initial scroll lag?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have set up a `3x18` "grid view" using the `UICollectionView` class. Each cell contains a `UIImageView` that is loaded from an `NSDictionary`. There are 18 images, totaling around "20 MB".

The problem I have is when I'm initially in the view, and I scroll from the top to the bottom, it's laggy. After that, the scrolling is as smooth as the Photos app.

Why is that the case? Is it because my images are too big?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dictionary = @{@"01"    : @[@"Image 1"],
                   @"02"    : @[@"Image 2"],
                   // etc etc 
                  };

    numOfImages = [ [dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    // Allows appropriate methods to be used
    self.pageantCollectionView.delegate = self;
    self.pageantCollectionView.dataSource = self;
}

// Populate each cell with specified data

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *number = [numOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSArray *imageByNumber = [dictionary objectForKey:number];

    NSString *name= [imageByNumber objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    cell.nameLabel.text = name;

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self getImage:name] ];

    // Set rounded corners
    CALayer * l = [cell.imageView layer];

    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];

    [l setCornerRadius:10.0];

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)colView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell* cell = [colView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CALayer * l = [cell layer];

    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];

    [l setCornerRadius:10.0];

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)colView didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UICollectionViewCell* cell = [colView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil;    
}
```

Does it have anything to do with the fact that I'm setting the corner radius for the "imageView" dynamically within `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, and also the corner radius for the cell itself within `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath`?

If that is the case, how can I go about statically creating the corner radius for the "imageView" and "cell" itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The delay is more likely to be the image loading using `[UIImage imageNamed:]` First time round, these are loaded from disk (slow). Subsequently they will be loaded from the memory cache, which will be fast. You will get a worse result, the larger your images.

Things to consider

- How large are you images (in pixel dimensions) compared with their view size? If they are substantially larger, you should consider providing thumbnail versions at the display size.
- Preloading. Is there a better place in the app to incur this delay? Such as during startup (before the collectionView is displayed? If so try loading them all (using imageNamed:) into an `NSDictionary` or an `NSCache` (that's like a dictionary that gets flushed out in low memory conditions)
- Asynchronous loading. Consider using `UIImage imageFromContentsOfFile:` instead, which you can put in a background thread (then load the image into the imageView on the main thread). Unlike `imageNamed` this method does not cache, but you can do that manually by adding the result to an `NSCache`. You will need to write a bit of code to favour getting the  image from the cache when available in preference to refetching it from disk.
  You *might* be OK doing this with `imageNamed` - but it is not thread-safe so you shouldn't really attempt it (see the comments alongside [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26562349/1375695)).
- *possibly* forcing an initial offscreen draw on a background thread before displaying the image on the main thread. This forces the image to decompress in the background. You would need to experiment with this technique in conjunction with the previous one to see if it really makes a difference for you.
- Cell initialisation. Anything that only needs to happen once to a cell, shouldn't be done in `cellForItem...`. You could move these things (such as your cell layer corner radius) into a cell `init` method, as Daniel Shaffer suggests. You should do this anyway, although I don't think this will be the main reason for your current scrolling woes.

Comment: 1. for 2x images: 827 by X, for 3x images: 1242 by Y......2. Which is better? NSDictionary or NSCache?....3.  I kind of get what you mean, but can you provide me an example? Thanks

Comment: @Pangu... 1/ Idon't understand your figures. If your cell image view is (say) 100 x 100 pts, what is your 2x image? 200x200px would be correct: if larger, you should provide thumbnails at the correct size 2/ `NSCache` is the correct storage object. 3/ Here's an [old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14624875/1375695) that might help

Comment: I apologize, I thought you meant the actual images I used. The cell image size is only 100x150. I could resize the actual images to that size, but I will be using those images in another View Controller on a bigger size scale, so having 2 versions of the same image is not efficient (I don't think).

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom `UICollectionViewCell`, and in the subclass of your cell in the `awakeFromNib` method, set the corner radius and anything else. This is to prevent it from modifying the layer EVERY time (as it currently does via the `cellForItem` method).

i.e.:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[colView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Also make sure to register the cell in `viewDidLoad` (you can find custom cell guides all over).

Comment: where does CustomCell cell = (CustomCell)[colView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] go? Sorry..